# Multi vs Single Layer RF Coil

Tags: rf, radio

Most of the literature on building radios from scratch implies the use of single-layer air core coils. Yet, most of the coils I see in old radios are multi-layer coils. Is there any advantage or disadvantage to using multiple layers? Why aren't more homebrewed radios built with multi-layer coils?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single layer coils are easier to build.

Multi-layer coils are more compact for the inductance, however generally have a higher self capacitance, so lower self resonant frequency (SRF).

Taken together, that means if you are instructing amateurs to build something that will work first time, specify single layer coils. If you are a manufacturer with time to design properly and an incentive to minimise use of materials, use multi-layer coils.